# Data sent to card io servers

Tags: card.io

It is my understanding that no card data is ever sent out, to any server.  All processing is happening on the device. Is this the case?

I did notice (via Charles Proxy) that one request is made to the host api.card.io
Are the card.io folks able to tell me what is being sent out?

### Below is the request details:

```
CONNECT api.card.io:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.card.io
User-Agent: card.io/icc (3.6.5 [Apr.21.2014-30fe])
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

≠©S[åVÜÃ∞È"≠/vΩœ§ãöΩœ–®ï∑Ñπ‹ÿ˜Jˇ¿$¿#¿
¿   ¿¿¿(¿'¿¿¿¿¿&¿%¿*¿)¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿
=</5
gk396api.card.io


Nåÿú\–˚Ù≠}Îöª‘Vó¶∫ˆ'⁄î@»ŸÆ∆2ëﬁÅÄË
Iè∏
˙
âB⁄B∫ø}CÈpE]ÜÂ9ÉΩ◊¨ƒ≠A¥48pO˛^ÿ†π ‹Ëñ5Á!fVeRêüŸ∂'¯Ÿˇj<©≈Ì[∏;.?m´ú°—Ë’,KπE_Íkˆt∑{ˇëgRºxDø^‰.Ù»§pm4Å_Ë‹UwÑºy¸&-I∂é’œáﬁ:g≠“«óOπ«ù¸Á—•Iﬁ)ÉﬂWŒú¬ºº‰NC¢–sHÙ˙ÃÎqcÓÌ⁄∑o++ùOÂWD˚¸Å$á´|ë|90˙X)◊U≠›di9eí¡"ytÂ°ÂÖ9hÊπ¬vu ys™∞ƒAÉ;Ê14óΩBÏv@sQ¬…T¿B˛ƒ\í°¢rÇ≥€≠c≥°]‚X0œ€’T]„ë"ñ,N@y¸H∫OSëAÃ‡⁄»df∑mLœÈ¥ÛW:˙1IQïÊ/Ø§d˙ﬁNÑ=çqRz≥ö«X'4(:âX!ﬁ<*Æ,}≈ËÎ{rÌ⁄ô∑µ+Åz'ÖsyÄ÷Xtjöf ÊËAJÿÜRÏÈ™ä’F|å!°Í›!kaå»—O˘˜9ÊÏ™Ãœ7ùxë5ËÒYËﬁpõ…—5XxÆòOÅÙÔÿc˘åZ‡˚W›ët∆ÌCê—mhy∞‘V>j-÷R8FÚd»¢ıî•¶≠_êx˙ÇSÏ≈Ù„"°Ë}‘∫m” “¡d@VêÖjöØÚºÓœø∑œ…~πMÂa5ﬁÙ:À6ò≠v“æ
®Òœõ”À ‰r¶¬£±#ú®˝q¬%^|b¡l: ÈÈ9KÊoç
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

card.io sends auth requests ("may this app scan cards?") and analytics data. None of that includes card data. I suspect you'll find that the wire data you captured is a binary plist.

Comment: Thank you Josh.  Are you, by any chance, able to elaborate on the 'analytics data' piece.  For me to be use this library, I need to go through a 'governance' process within my company, where I will be asked that question.

Comment: I'm not going to document it here, no. It mostly relates to user experience and computer vision, and it doesn't contain any sensitive data. I already told you the format, and you can already intercept the requests, so I suggest that you just dig a bit yourself.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  Appreciate your time.